# Updating content while doing a fadeOut and fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to update content of a dynamic quiz, when you answer the question you click on the next button and then the section its supposed to fade out, update content and then fade in again with the new question.

This is the piece of code I'm using to do it

```
function changeQuestion(){
    questions.fadeOut();
    // first, check answer
    if($("#myForm input[type='radio']:checked").length ==1){
        //add the answer to the answers array
        answers[number] = $("#myForm input[type='radio']:checked").val(); 
        // increment the number
        number++;

        // then, move to next question OR show results
        if (number < allQuestions.length) {
            $('#back').show();
            addQuestionAndAnswers();

        }else {
            displayResult();
        }
    }else{
        alert('please select an answer before proceed');
    }
    questions.fadeIn(); 
}
```

But when I click the next button to content update while the section is fading out... I've been trying doing a function fadeOut() that fade the content and then call the changeQuestion function but I had the same result. I'll leave a fiddle of what I'm trying to do I hope someone can help me.

http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/Wn8Qg/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing your `changeQuestion()` function to:

```
function changeQuestion() {
    if ($("#myForm input[type='radio']:checked").length == 1) {
        questions.fadeOut(400, function () {
            // first, check answer

            //add the answer to the answers array
            answers[number] = $("#myForm input[type='radio']:checked").val();
            // increment the number
            number++;

            // then, move to next question OR show results
            if (number < allQuestions.length) {
                $('#back').show();
                addQuestionAndAnswers();

            } else {
                displayResult();
            }
            questions.fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
        alert('please select an answer before proceed');
    }
}
```

That way, by evaluating if there's a selected answer before attempting to fade you won't get a fade if there's no selected answer; also since your making the content change after the fade is complete, your effect should look as intended...

[**Click here for Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/2WV6u/1/)

Comment: this worked really good for me i was wondering if its ok to use an anonym function to do that?....i was trying to do it without anonym function but couldn't get it, the way you do it works really good :)

Comment: Yup there's no problem if you use an anonymous function in this case, unless you were planning to call it from somewhere else (which I doubt), but in that situation you could just declare the function outside and call it from the `fadeOut()`

Comment: well i tried to call it form outside butt didnt work :( ahahah but with the anonym function it works really good i stick to yoour answer ty very much...i left the fiddle so you can see now you can go next and back with the fading effect!

http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/Wn8Qg/18/

Comment: Looks good! And it's always nice to help, just remember it's also cool to upvote helpful answers/questions ;)

Comment: i accepted your answer, thank you very much while im learning javascript cause some day i wanna be a front end developer, books and stack overflow have been helping me a lot to understand programming!

Comment: Just keep it up and you'll get it, stackoverflow is an amazing site and as long as you have a positive attitude and are willing to learn more you should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the completion function for the `fadeOut()` so that you only replace the content AFTER the fade has finished.  See the [jQuery doc for `.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) for more info.

Something like this:

```
function changeQuestion(){
    questions.fadeOut(function() {
        // first, check answer
    if($("#myForm input[type='radio']:checked").length ==1){
            //add the answer to the answers array
            answers[number] = $("#myForm input[type='radio']:checked").val(); 
            // increment the number
            number++;

            // then, move to next question OR show results
            if (number < allQuestions.length) {
                $('#back').show();
                addQuestionAndAnswers();

            }else {
                displayResult();
            }
        }else{
            alert('please select an answer before proceed');
        }
        questions.fadeIn(); 
    });
}
```